# add a variable counter to jquery id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code below currently and it works fine.

```
$('.clickable').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#toggle').slideToggle();
});

$('.clickable1').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#toggle1').slideToggle();
});
```

I need to refactor it to work miracles for me in terms of looping. I want to have one statement that add a number to the id toggle and class clickable using a loop for a maximum number 5 times.

Something like below

```
for(i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    $('.clickable'.' + i + ').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#toggle'.' + i + ').slideToggle();
    });
}
```

Comment: `$('.clickable' + i  )` yse like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a more flexible solution, without limiting to a certain number of object, you could use another approach.

Using a common class for al clickable elements (ie clickable), and an attribute to set the `clickable` target slide.

Html:

```
<a href='#' class='clickable' data-target='1'>Slide</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.clickable').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#toggle' + $(this).data('target')).slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:[solution](https://jsfiddle.net/ionutmihai1995/c71dxjyh/)

HTML

```
 <a href="#" class="clickable1" data-target="1">
    Words to click
 </a>
 <div class="toggle1" class="hidden-to-show">
 <ul> 
   <li>Item One</li>
   <li>Item One</li>
   <li>Item One</li>
   <li>Item One</li>
 </ul> 
 </div>
 <a href="#" class="clickable2" data-target="2">Words to click</a>
   <div class="toggle2" class="hidden-to-show"> 
    <ul> 
     <li>Item One</li> 
     <li>Item One</li> 
     <li>Item One</li> 
     <li>Item One</li> 
    </ul> 
 </div>
 <br>
```

JS

```
$('a').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.toggle' + $(this).attr('data-target')).slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: It is different one. He makes mistakes like declaring more elements with same ID.And it is more effective

Comment: he shouldn't declare more elements using the same id at all